# How to erase hair from a model to leave it bald?

Tags: modeling

I'm beginning to practice blender and bought and downloaded a simple body model, but I want to erase the hair to leave it bald, but I don't know what tool to use. Any advice? If it's useful, it looks like the hair was modeled separately because experimenting with some tools I was able to lift some parts and underneath are the ears of the model complete.

Comment: HI, welcome, maybe show at least a screenshot of your model "hair" separately modeled, to let others better understand. Isn't enough to select the heir model part and hide or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing <kbd>H</kbd> or delete the object or in the outliner there is  list of meshes you have in front of you.